# How do I stop the search helper from popping up in my browser?

Tags: dictionary

I'm trying to select text in chrome, and half the time I get this weird popup while selecting the first word, It's really annoying and I'd like to disable it, at least in chrome.

[image: Demonstration of odd behavior]

I've never experienced this behavior before today, I'm on a newly issued rMBP at work, I haven't seen this on my personal laptop, or other OSX devices, or windows or linux for that matter.  I'm just not even sure where to start in terms of disabling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it, it appears to be part of the `Trackpad Settings` regarding `Look up and data detectors` ... I changed the setting from `Force click with one finger` to `tap with three fingers`.

[image: related setting]